# Probability problem on ideal coin

Tags: probability-theory

Question gotten from a study on  probability theory given by my supervisor.

There  are 3 coins identical  in appearance, one of which is ideal and the other two biased with probabilities 1/3 and 2/3 respectively  for a head. One coin is taken at random  and tossed twice. If a head appears both times,  what is the probability  that the ideal coin  was chosen?

```
             My solution
```

P(coin) ={(HH) , (HT) , (TH) , (TT)} 
The probability  that the ideal coin was chosen  is;
P(ideal_coin) *P(Head of head appearing both times) =1/3*1/4=1/12

Is my solution right?

Comment: Please sir,  Don't  understand  what you mean by adding more context??

Comment: Answer the questions I posed in my comment.  That will supply the necessary context.

Comment: @Sammie please add important facts such as where you got this problem from and what you have attempted so far. This will help us determine exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: I have added sir.  Thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bayes theorem is your friend here. Let define the following events: 
A: chose the ideal coin 
B: chose a biased coin
C: head appears both time

You are looking for the following conditional probability: $P(A|C)$, which is equal to $\frac{P(C|A)P(A)}{P(C)}$(Bayes theorem).

$P(C|A)$ is the probability of getting two heads with the ideal coin which is equal to $\frac{1}{4}$

There are 3 possibilities to get 2 heads, you chose one of the biased coins(2 possibilities because there are two of them) or the ideal one and then get the 2 head. Which means $P(C) = 2 P(C|B)P(B) + P(C|A)P(A)$.

Now you can calculate the wanted probability

Comment: Thank you sir..